# Application Slow After Change fontsize in a WPF richtextbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, fonts, richtextbox

i am working with WP richtextbox.i done to navigate each line from current caret position to nextline,previousline etc.it works fine.i need to dynamically change fontsize in richtextbox.

i used this below methods to change font size:

```
 myrichtextbox.SetValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, fontSizedouble +10);

  myrichtextbox.FontSize = (txtAppendValue.FontSize + 10);
```

it works.But after execute this methods,the other functionality execution time taken is high.Before that `NavigateNextLine()` taken 15ms to 20ms.After execution it takes 40 to 50 ms.i continuously call the fontSize 4,5 times then the `NavigateNextLine()` takes 100ms t0 120 ms.

```
public void NavigateNextLine()
{
  Int32 lineNumber;
                txtAppendValue.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(-int.MaxValue, out lineNumber);
                Int32 iLineIndex = System.Math.Abs(lineNumber);
                Int32 iCurrentStart = 0;
                Int32 iCurWordLength = 0;


                for (Int32 icnt = 0; icnt <= iLineIndex; icnt++)
                {
                    m_strCurLineText = GetLineText(txtAppendValue.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(lineNumber), 0, null);
                    iCurrentStart = iCurrentStart + m_strCurLineText.Length;
                    lineNumber += 1;
                }
  String[] strArr = m_strCurLineText.Split(' ');
                if (strArr.Length > 0)
                {
                    iCurWordLength = strArr[0].Length; // Get the first word length of current line
                    if (iCurWordLength == 0)
                    {
                        iCurWordLength = strArr[1].Length;
                        iCurrentStart = iCurrentStart + 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    iCurWordLength = m_strCurLineText.Length; //to get single word line length
                }

                NewStart = iCurrentStart;
}





 String GetLineText(TextPointer TextPointer, int LineRltv = 0, string Default = null)
        {
            TextPointer tp1 = TextPointer.GetLineStartPosition(LineRltv);
            if (tp1 == null)
            {
                return Default;
            }
            else
            {
                tpNextLine2 = tp1.GetLineStartPosition(1);

                TextRange tr = null;
                if (tpNextLine2 == null)
                {
                    tpNextLine2 = txtAppendValue.Document.ContentEnd;
                }
                tr = new TextRange(tp1, tpNextLine2);
                return tr.Text;
            }
        }
```

SO whats the problem?how to resolve it?

regards
Arjun

Comment: post your code for rest of functionality

Comment: @ Muds : Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Both should work:**

```
txtAppendValue.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (double)10);
```

OR

```
txtAppendValue.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 10.0)
```

Comment: @ Vivek : Both should work.my problem is after executing this one other functionality execution speed slow.i also tried this one.

Comment: @arjun ok got to find the solution