# How do I Increase Fontsize for text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, font-size

How to set font size in each time i call a method.i want to use `richtextbox.ApplyPropertyValue()` method. I already tried

```
myrichtextbox.SetValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, fontSizedouble +10);

myrichtextbox.FontSize = (myrichtextbox.FontSize + 10);
```

Comment: it will work only once am i right ?

Comment: problem is you have two control one is myrichtextbox and second is txtAppendValue you are adding txtAppendValue.FontSize + 10 to myrichtextbox and it will set size only once because txtAppendValue.FontSize  is never changed

Comment: myrichtextbox.FontSize = (myrichtextbox.FontSize + 10);

Comment: @Darshan : I update my question.Actually other functionality like textpointer and textrange was slow executed after the above two methods are used and the above code used again and again not only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rich text box you need selection--

try this

```
TextSelection selectedText = myrichtextbox.Selection;

selectedText.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontSizeProperty, fontSizedouble +10);
```

For all text you can try this --

```
TextRange allText = new TextRange(MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

allText.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontSizeProperty, fontSizedouble +10);
```

And to change size again and again you need to check size for text not richTextBox, do this --

```
TextRange allTextRange = new TextRange(MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

var size = (double)allTextRange.GetPropertyValue(FontSizeProperty);

allTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontSizeProperty, size + 10);
```

Comment: @ Muds : it only increase the selected text,i want to change the whole richtextbox text and again and again i want to increase the font.

Comment: @ Muds : In first press it works.after that selected text font only increased.

Comment: Arjun, did you see my last update, just use  last one you will be fine.

Comment: @ Muds : Ya.i used that last one only. After this code block i used to textrange.clearallproperties() method for another purpose.it affected to ur codeblock?

Comment: why clear all properties ? and if that so is needed I reckon you need another question for that, for now this solves the raised question, doesn't ?

Comment: @ Mud : Actually each word highlight and navigate to the end of the document in my application.so i need to use clearallproperties for clearing previous properties.in font increase/decrease i used the above two methods.its working but cause to slow the other functionalities.thats y i ask any other method to set the font.but your codeblock will apply to richtextbox not set to richtextbox.thats y it cleared.

Comment: dude tbh I did not get what your issue is now, can you raise another question as it seems totally different to this one ?

Comment: @ Mud : Check this link. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870256/application-slow-after-change-fontsize-in-a-wpf-richtextbox/34870386#34870386)

Answer (score 1):

Change it from your `FlowDocument`.

```
this.Document.FontSize = this.Document.FontSize + 10;
```